# Ordering and paging records based on association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have two Models here associated as such:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  ...
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

A customer can have many orders and an order can belong to one customer. The thing is that I'm displaying a listed table where I show the following field values

```
ORDER ID| CUSTOMER NAME |...
```

Customer name refers to customer[:name] - I found out that you can sort by using the find method and passing in a join like so:

```
Order.find(:all, :joins => :customer, :order => 'customer.name asc')
```

however I need to paginate the results here and it seems I can't do something like this - I'm using the Kaminari gem here for pagination:

```
Order.find(:all, :joins => :customer, :order => 'customer.name asc').page(5) 
# doesn't work throws an error nomethoderror on page
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try same thing on rails console and post the exact error. I didn't find any error except customer.name in order. I think it should be customers.name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the "new" Rails 3 query interface:

```
Order.joins(:customer).order("customers.name asc").page(5)
```

Comment: I'm going with your suggestion - even though all the answers are equally awesome :) thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
Order.joins(:customer).select('orders.*, customers.name as customers_name').order('customers_name ASC').page(5)
```

Works for me with Kaminari gem.
Also you'll have customers_name method on every object result. 
You can find more about select method here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

'page' works on for Kaminari, its not Order's method

```
orders = Order.joins(:customer).order("customers.name asc")

Kaminari.paginate_array(orders).page(page)
```